# How to restrict access to subdomain based on IP (AWS)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-application-load-balancer, amazon-waf, ip-blocking

We want to block access for unknown ip-addresses to specific subdomains.

We are using one aws application loadbalancer that forwards (subdomain) traffic to specific ECS target groups. Some of these subdomains should not be accessable by unknown ip-addresses.

I considered using AWS WAF to block the ip's but it looks like i cant specify to which subdomains the rule should apply.

Comment: you should aim to allow access for specified IP-ranges via the SG attached to the ALB not block unkown IP addresses.... you are approaching this wrong imo.

Comment: I'm not sure ip-ranges are approriat. For example i want to only allow the office ip and my home ip to reach subdomain1.site.com, but every ip can reach subdomain2.site.com.

Comment: There is no concept of "blocking a domain". A domain name simply resolves to an IP address. If you want to limit access to a Load Balancer, then configure the Security Group associated with the Load Balancer to only allow access from your desired IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

> I considered using AWS WAF to block the ip's but it looks like i cant specify to which subdomains the rule should apply.

That's correct. You **can't** block "access" to dns name. Internet does not work like that. You have to block access to resources pointed to by the dns name, such as an ec2 instance or load balancer. But anyone will always be able to "access" your domain.

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply need to use security groups and then specify the ips allowed to access the subdomains resources.

1. Create instance for each subdomain.
2. Configure it's Security Group inbound rules.
3. Create a route 53 record for your subdomains and point then to your instances.